# Is half life for first order is depend on the stochiometric coefficient of reactant or product?

Tags: kinetics

[image]
I took k=6.93x10^(-2) as given in ques and use the half life formula for 1st order kinetics and solve and finally get 10 min as a ans but right ans is 5 min and i m not able to get that..... Plse tell where i m doing mistake??

Comment: Please 1) *Type* out your question instead of posting a picture, 2) Include your thoughts and the *entire* method you used to tackle the problem... we aren't here to do your homework for you, and 3) Watch your sentence construction ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the reaction has the form $aA \rightarrow B + C $ then the rate at which *B* and *C* are produced is $1/a$ of the rate at which A disappears, thus
$$ -\frac{1}{a}\frac{dA}{dt}= \frac{dB}{dt}= \frac{dC}{dt}=kA$$

On this basis the half-life should be $5$ minutes in your question.

Comment: Ok got it i try to find it by the rate of apperance of O2 as given in question.... Now this help me lot to tackle next prblm... Thnx